# Efficiently adding a fixed real numbered value to a set of elements in an array

Tags: list-manipulation

Imagine I'm trying to add some value $r$ to each element in a very large array $L$.  Take for example:

```
L = Table[RandomReal[{0,1}],{q,1,10^7}];
r = 0.0032;
```

I can effectively add $r$ to each element in $L$ by writing:

```
L = Table[L[[q]]+r,{q,1,Length[L]}];
```

This operation takes about $\approx 322$ milliseconds.  However, is there a better / faster way to proceed?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Take advantage of listability -- meaning that you do not have to loop through the list, just add `r` to the list.

```
Timing[L1 = Table[L[[q]] + r, {q, 1, Length[L]}];]
(* {1.288042, Null} *)
```

faster listable alternative:

```
Timing[L2 = L + r;]
(* {0.339668, Null} *)

L1 == L2
(* True  *)
```

Timings on old Mac running V8.

Answer (score 1):

This can speeded up even more by eliminating `Table` as well as using listability.
Here are timings from my system.

```
r = 0.0032;
SeedRandom[42]; 
Timing[t1 = Table[RandomReal[{0, 1}], {q, 1, 10^7}];
  t2 = Table[t1[[q]] + r, {q, 1, Length[t1]}];]
```

> {1.331451, Null}

```
SeedRandom[42];
Timing[tbl = RandomReal[1., 10^7] + r;]
```

> {0.243818, Null}

```
tbl == t2
```

> True